# Why don't values persist on Postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

My home page has a list of product options each giving the user a different account level on sign up. Each option presents a "Sign Up" button which takes the user to the `/Identity/Account/Register` page to sign up.

I need to communicate to the Register page which option the user selected.

1. I can't use Sessions because that's apparently been taken away
2. I can't use Cookies because that's apparently been taken away
3. ViewData values don't persist when I submit the form
4. Querystring values don't persist when I submit the form
5. Global variable values don't persist when I submit the form
6. I can't set properties of the viewmodel when the page is loaded initially (NullReferenceException)

When the Register page loads, the value is there, but when I submit the form, it disappears.

I'm at a loss. By what mechanism am I meant to get this required information across?

For the most part my code is pretty much just standard boilerplate stuff:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public int AccountLevel { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null, int acclevel = 1)
    {
        AccountLevel = acclevel;
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null, int acclevel = 0)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (acclevel == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(acclevel));

            Input.LicenseCount = acclevel * 10;

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, Name = Input.FirstName, Surname = Input.Surname, PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber, SaIdNumber = Input.IdNumber, LicensesCount = Input.LicenseCount };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, nameof(SystemRoles.AppUser));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                //await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Here's the Page (this is using Pages with the PageModel for some reason, rather than Views and Controllers - it scaffolded this way when I added Identity).

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Surname"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.IdNumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.IdNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.IdNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto information to correct my ignorance would be more helpful than simply pointing it out, thanks.

Comment: And you believe that if I was in a position to understand the concepts as documented that I'd still bother asking here? You just assumed I'm lazy and didn't google, rather than I didn't understand what I'd easily found on a google search? (Spoiler alert: I did find that exact page yesterday and didn't understand it).

Comment: I created a variable as part of the model (see updated code) into which I put the value of `acclevel` in `OnGet` but that value had been reset `OnPostAsync`

Comment: Done. Please accept my apologies for being short with you. I'm being pressured to finish this project and I'm really aggravated by the whole situation at the moment. Its no excuse but I hope you can at least understand the pressure I'm under.

Comment: FYI: I hate MS for the stupid decision of adding Razor Pages and the even more stupid reason for moving Identity to this horrible mess. Can you just add, after the `<form>` tag opening, a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountLevel)`?

Comment: See I knew I was missing something simple... Thanks that's solved it. If you could put an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept (I'll even upvote if it includes specific details on how to do this with sessions lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I don't work with Razor Pages, so someone with knowledge in that technology might have a better answer.*

You can use a hidden field in the form to keep the value on POST-back:

```
<form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountLevel)
    @*OR, TagHelper way*@
    <input asp-for="AccountLevel" type="hidden"/>
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    ....
</form>
```

This is also fairly easy to do with sessions [after you enable them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-session-state):

```
public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null, int acclevel = 1)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("AccountLevel", acclevel);
    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    int accountLevel = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("AccountLevel");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, it's worth noting (since I didn't see it on the linked reference, so I figure others probably won't either), that the `services.AddSession` block needs to at least be after `services.AddMvc` for some reason. It only worked after I put it there.

Answer (score 1):

The only data that exists after a request is what's sent along with that request. Even in the case of sessions, the crucial session identifier must be transmitted by the client to the server in the request in order to restore that session.

Any data you retrieved from the database must either be posted or queried out again. Additionally, no data should be posted that the user should not be explicitly allowed to change. As a result, most data should to be queried again.

As far as which option the user selected goes, that of course should be posted. However, the actual details of the selected plan and the other plan options should be obtained from querying that database again. That will be necessary, for example, if you need to redisplay the form following the post, due to a validation error.